# SwiftUI List with ForEach works in one VStack but not in second one

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm at a complete loss for why a List I'm trying to create (with a `ForEach`) in `SwiftUI` is behaving the way that it is. I have an `ObservedObject` that I verified in the inspector has the data that I'm expecting. In the first `VStack`, I can create the List with the `ForEach` and it outputs just fine. In the second `VStack`, I get no data output.

```
struct WorkoutPreview: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  @ObservedObject var workoutSessionExercises: WorkoutSessionExercises

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("Welcome to your workout! Below are the exercises and bands you've selected for each.")
          .padding()
        Text("We found \(workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises.count) workouts.")
          .padding()

        // This List (with ForEach) works fine and produces output.
        List {
          ForEach(0..<workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises.count) { index in
            Text(self.workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises[index].exerciseName)
          }
        }
      }

      // The exact same List (with ForEach) in this VStack produces no results.
      VStack {
        List {
          ForEach(0..<workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises.count) { index in
            Text(self.workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises[index].exerciseName)
          }
        }
      }

      Spacer()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you have 2 VStacks that are not one below the other in the View, and so you can't see the second list.
To fix your problem wrap your VStacks in another VStack, such as:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {   //  <------
            VStack {
                Text("Welcome to your workout! Below are the exercises and bands you've selected for each.").padding()
                Text("We found \(workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises.count) workouts.").padding()
                // This List (with ForEach) works fine and produces output.
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises.count) { index in
                        Text(self.workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises[index].exerciseName)
                    }
                }
            }
            // The exact same List (with ForEach) in this VStack produces no results.
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises.count) { index in
                        Text(self.workoutSessionExercises.workoutExercises[index].exerciseName)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }         //  <------
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked wrapping them both in a `VStack`. Can you help me understand why two `VStack` elements at the same level can't access the same object? I'm confused how they both live at the same hierarchy level, but only the first one can see it.

Comment: NavigationView should wrap around an overall container such as; List, ScrollView, VStack, HStack, Form etc... If not you get the problem you encountered. Why I don't really know. Apple documentation does not explain. 

To obtain two views one after the other vertically they need to be in a VStack.

There is nothing wrong with your lists accessing the workoutExercises objects. The problem is still the same even if you use Text("...") or any other views instead.

Where do the those views get displayed, I don't know, my guess is, only the first one gets displayed and the others get ignored.